# Xamarin forms: How to parse HTML Data having video links?

Tags: html, video, xamarin.forms

I have video links(Vimeo video) and normal texts in my HTML data. I am using `Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel` for parsing the HTML data. But it is not effective, the links are not clickable on the iPhone. Also, the video links are missing when coming to UI.

I have added my sample HTML data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PwWQUxTrMKRER4rIo7EIJLlxpogJqRkF). I am using a webview for showing videos. So the video links should open on the app itself using webview or any other property. And show the remaining description as normal text. I need a UI like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14UL3xZkZgqNc2G_GIUO3Bq1ZUd4NMh_6). How can I do this? My [current UI](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CziBSI9ayoUS6CUy9JroCcVqMhbzqKLr) using `Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel`.

Comment: Can't you just Keep it the way you have it and just add a video player? then just pass the players source threw a binding that you can parse the same way you are now? if i'm understanding this correctly Using something like Xam.Forms.VideoPlayer/

Comment: @RoyAurele Initially I tried video player, but it needs video extension like .mp4. My videos did not have extensions, that's why I choose webview for playing video.

Comment: Noted, I am a little confused here So when you parse your not getting the Video source's to pull threw to the webview?

Comment: @RoyAurele I tried to set the HTML data as a webview source, but that is also not working.

Comment: Did you try this demo? if it could running normally?https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175969/xamarin-forms-how-to-parse-html-data-having-video-links

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I have tried that, but getting an exception. I have posted exception details on that thread.

Comment: Now you do not know how to use `Content = web`? it is Xamarin.Forms.View Content like this thread:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage.content?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I am directly setting it on XAML, like <local:MyWebView>

Comment: Ok, Is that worked as normal?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT When I tried like that the app breaks with an exception, please see the below screenshotrs,https://drive.google.com/open?id=1am5TgnpYGJOUT1OM7-reu_uNJPLOfsQk, https://drive.google.com/open?id=15u59wQeIOZeUk65RhtTTHE01DPiVrWkg

Comment: Did you add the settings like this thread?https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/issues/11#issuecomment-219071491

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I am using `Fonts provided by application` key for adding font ttf files